# Issue installing Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I keep getting this error when i try to install Angular/Cli via git-bash/chocolaty;

```
Josh@DESKTOP-BKT7CAR MINGW64 ~ (main)
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.2.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 253 packages, and audited 254 packages in 16s

16 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Can someone help me fix this. I have the latest NPM/NodeJS versions installed.

Comment: There are no errors. As for the warnings, they each describe exactly what the problem is

Comment: after you've done this, does ng command works? if yes, then all went good, those are just warnings for dependencies related to the angular cli

Comment: I'm currently going to school for Software Development, and taking Full-Stack development classes on my own via Udemy & EDX. So i'm still learning. Thus I don't know what ng command you are referring to lol....is that like the version check command for angular or something. i.e. npm -v ?

Answer (score 1):

There're not errors Just warning I think that our only option is to wait for the package maintainer's to get their dependencies straight ignore it and hope for a update soon.